# Is it a good practice to test a method that update properties?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm creating tests, and every time I need to update a simple object, I create tests that check if all properties that I will pass through the method are changed.

For instance:

```
public class User {
   public string name { get; private set }
   public string email { get; private set }
   public string password { get; private set }

   public void UpdateData(string name, string email, string password){
    //update fields
 }
}
```

Test class:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Update_Data(){
   var arrange = {
      name: "NewName",
      Email: "NewEmail@Something.com",
      Password: "123456"
   }

   var user = new User();
   user.UpdateData(arrange.name, arrange.Email, arrange.Password);

   //Assert user.name equals arrange.name  
   //Assert user.email equals arrange.email
   //Assert user.password equals arrange.password
}
```

But I'm confused if it's a good practice to do so many asserts, and it's very boring to check all properties that I'm updating were really updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily bad practice to do many asserts but there are definitely benefits to keeping tests to perform a single assert:

- tests stay more focused
- easier to understand what is being tested
- assertions won't mask other assertions, ie if user.name assertion fails then user.email will never get executed, which results in longer feedback cycles

What sorts of regressions are you trying to prevent from happening with your tests? Is it effective in detecting those regressions from happening? Does the compiler protect you in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The contract for `updateData` is to perform an update on those elements. Therefore, you need to test it. However, you need not explicitly test it. If another part of your test *covers* the updateData portion, you can rely on that coverage as an implict test.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your actual method does something more than just set some properties. If not, I would not test these methods as it's too trivial for testing.

In case it is more complicated you will need some unit tests. As for your issue with the various asserts in a single method, I tend to set up my tests a bit differently so that the asserts are separated.

I'd set up and execute the code in the initialize method and then arrange the asserts in separate methods:

```
[TestClass]
public class UpdatingData
{
    User user;
    dyanmic arrange = {
       Name: "NewName",
       Email: "NewEmail@Something.com",
       Password: "123456"
    };

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Because(){      
       user = new User();
       user.UpdateData(arrange.Name, arrange.Email, arrange.Password);

       //Assert user.name equals arrange.name  
       //Assert user.email equals arrange.email
       //Assert user.password equals arrange.password
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdatesTheName() => Assert.Equals(user.Name, arrange.Name);

    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdatesTheEmail() => Assert.Equals(user.Email, arrange.Email);

    [TestMethod]
    public void UpdatesThePassword() => Assert.Equals(user.Password, arrange.Password);

}
```